# How to make optimization's test regex expression work in webpack4?

Tags: node.js, optimization, webpack

the test regex expression :
test: `/[\\/]node_modules[\\/]@babel[\\/]polyfill//`
doesn't work in optimization,
but!
test: `/[\\/]node_modules[\\/]react-dom[\\/]/`
and
test: `/[\\/]node_modules[\\/]react[\\/]/`
work correctly.

Comment: I want all the third-party libraries dependency to be built into a separate target file(node_modules/**),it's better define it in one cacheGroup,
like :

"dependencies": {  
"@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",  
"react": "^16.8.3",  
"react-dom": "^16.8.3"  
}  

will be :
app.js  
polyfill.js  
react.js  
react-dom.js  
redux.js

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that `/[\\/]node_modules[\\/]@babel[\\/]polyfill//` is not escaping the last slash, it should be

`/[\\/]node_modules[\\/]@babel[\\/]polyfill[\\/]/`